# Android - Execute different code for different devices

Tags: android, version, device, unsatisfiedlinkerror

my first question a few days ago didn't get any answers and I still couldn't find anything helpful on the web, so I'll give it a second try with a more generally asked question (I'm working on this for my internship and I grow rather desperate cause I don't have any (more) ideas how to solve this:

I'm writing an app, which should generally work on Android phones, but support a certain behaviour, which is currently only supported by one device (digital radio on LG Stylus 2). On said device the app works fine, but it crashes with UnsatisfiedlinkError on any other device.

I want to make the app detect the device on start and only execute the digital radio code when it is run on the right device, otherwise I want to execute different code (a web streaming radio).

I'm not necessarily asking for code, but for what would be the right approach to go about this conceptually. Any answers are much appreciated.

Thanks guys

Dave

Comment: Show how you are invoking the code that generated the exception and add logcat for stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following for this purpose.

```
String model = Build.MODEL;

if(model.equalsIgnoreCase("LG Stylus 2")
{
    //do your task
}
```

Comment: Thanks, MezzyDroid, that's already pretty helpful! :)
Any ideas, how I can tell to system to exclude a certain (unsupported) library on start up, when it' s not the one device?

Comment: I dont think that is possible ..... because gradle does not allow to suppress library to run on certain device. But you can get model name and use that specific functionality only when LG Stylus is running otherwise disable that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use the build flavors feature in gradle and Android Studio. This shows you to build multiple APKs for different configurations. For example, you can create a build flavor for LG Stylus 2 support. Then create an AndroidManifest.XML file with the proper `<uses-feature>` tags. Also add custom dependencies and Java code to the new flavor.